# Unable to deploy RD Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, gateway, remote-desktop-services

I was just trying to deploy my RD Gateway but it failed. The deployment shows succeeded, but the RD Gateway icon doesn't grey out. That means i can still redeploying it again and again.

So i went to Event viewer to check if there's any error logs and I got this.

> Sources: Rdms-UI, Event ID: 4119
>
> `RD Gateway Configuration Failed on %ServerName% With Error: Unable to configure the RD Gateway server: %ServerName%. The error is 2147749890.`

When  i search the web for the error i got this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/798ea7ea-99cc-4102-b944-1751aab7f3f1/unable-to-configure-rd-gateway-role-services-in-windows-server-2012?forum=winserverTS), but this doesn't solve the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point is the IIS and WAS. I ended up reinstalling them. At the same time, the RD Gateway has been removed. Redo the steps and it works perfectly now.